# In C and C++, can a compiler store an unamed object generated from a expression, if that same expression is reused, but the result is unchanged?

Tags: c++, c, optimization

I'm mostly interested in C and C++, but I think this question can also apply to other languages.

My question is, if an unamed object or value is generated from the evaluation of an expression or function, can it be cached if that same expression or function is later called, and the compiler recognizes that the result is unchanged.

Demonstrated in the below examples

```c
    x=(a+b)/c;
    y=(a+b)/c;
    a+=x;
    z=(a+b)/c;
```

and

```c
int my_function()
{
    return (a+b)/c;
}

int main()
{
    x=my_function();
    y=my_function();
    a+=x;
    z=my_function();
}
```

The compiler will cache the result of the expression (a+b)/c, or the function my_function when assigning x, and change the assignments of y to a reference to the cached result, without the calculation or function having to be performed again. But since their is a visible change to that expression or function with a+=x, z is assigned by reevaluating (a+b)/c, or calling my_function a second time.
This question also applies to larger data types, like structs and classes, which I imagined could be assigned to the current stack frame like local variables, but unnamed and not directly accessible by the programmer.

While typing this, I saw another question asking the same thing about Python, referencing the C++ standard, which stated that a temporary object does not last after the statment it is created in.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046606/are-temporary-references-automatically-cleared-in-python
So, my question is, even if that object no longer exists within the rules of the language, can it still be retained by the the compiler as a form of optimization, if it detects that within the rules of the language the same evaluation or function call will yield the same result.

I want to effectively treat a function call or expression like a stored variable in situations where I know it will return the same result, without it performing the evaluation or function call each time.  Do I have to assign the result to a named variable to achieve this.

The compiler I am using is GCC.

Comment: You will have to examine the generated assembly. There are no guarantees, compilers can do anything they feel like so long as the code exhibits the correct behaviour.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Thank you for your response. Even if I can't guarantee it, have compilers been known to do this? Is this something I can expect, or should I declare a named variable each time I want to reuse a result from a complex evaluation.

Comment: You should worry about clarity first and only worry about performance once you have shown that this is actually on your hot path.

Comment: Some edits might reopen the question and improve reception. I don't think the title really captures what you're asking in the body. Also, if you're going to mention another question please provide a link to it. Oh and welcome to the site.

Comment: Compilers are smart in some ways, dumb in others. It tends to be difficult for compilers to reason about temporal relationships. I wouldn't expect any compiler to do your optimization unless some code calls the target function multiple times, the compiler inlines the calls, and the compiler sees that the value cannot change. However, the compiler might not be able to prove that if pointers are involved due to “aliasing”. I would not expect the compiler to change a function so that it always caches the return value, you'd have to implement that manually. You could write a Clang plugin though.

Comment: There are no guarantees but a combination of these factors will increase the chance that the compiler will cache the computed value: (1) Compiled at the highest optimization setting (`-O3`); (2) The computation happens in a function that is purely arithmetic and is purely side-effect-free; does not call any other non-pure functions; (3) The computation only involves logic or integer arithmetic; does not involve floating point; does not trigger any of the unspecified integer arithmetic behaviors listed on the C++ specification; (4) the function is fully inlined into the parent function; etc.

Comment: It does happen sometimes, for trivial and repetitive calculations (such as reading from a member variable and then performing a simple arithmetic operation on it), because this is how compiler optimization achieves its goal of magically making code run faster. This is why one has to look at the generated assembly (or machine code) to see how well the compiler is optimizing giving a piece of code and a particular bag of compiler options.

Comment: My educated guess is that what you are describing is not worth the trouble. Keeping track of what was parsed and compiled earlier will likely be more expensive than mindlessly generating it again.

Comment: @MartinMaat, Do you mean literal objects and values that are evaluated on compile time? My question is refering to the behaviour of my code on runtime. If evaluations and function calls are stored as local variables or objects, even if no such objects are declared in the source, and subsequent calls to that expression or function are replaced by the compiler with reference to that object. Sorry I took a while to respond.

Comment: @rwong, In the cases you refer to, would an expression like (a+b)/c be eligible to be stored as an object, but not something like a function call.

Comment: @amon,@rwong, If a function is fully side effect free, can the result be temporarily stored like I described, even if it is not inlined.

Comment: @SingleQuestion I am still/again not sure what you are asking, your questions seem to be moving targets. There is no such thing as a stored evaluation. A compiler is not going to create variables or objects unless explicitly instructed to do so by the compiled code. It is not supposed to be smart about anything when it comes to the resulting logic. That would be pretty annoying. The optimization issue you are trying to see solved by a compiler is really an application level problem. At that level caching results is a common thing. But it would be coded logic.

Comment: @MartinMaat, I think I might have been misusing terms. When I refered to evaluations, I meant the resulting value or object generated on runtime by an expression, or returned by a function. I was asking if a compiler can designate a local object to store that result, to substitute repeating a calculation or function call, in cases where the result is the same each time.

Comment: Functionally, referencing that object will have the same result as repeating that calculation or function, and will not affect the behaviour of the source code.

Comment: @SingleQuestion No the compiler cannot do that because it has no way of knowing whether that would be beneficial or not. This is typically up to the application programmer to do (or not). Compilers do optimize but typically by making things simpler and you would have to tell it upfront for what to optimize. Because the effect of the optimization you describe and whether it would be an optimization at all, very much depends on the way the software is going to be used at runtime, this would not be something any compiler would do.

Comment: C and C++ have the “as if” rule: The compiler can do anything it likes, any optimisation, if the code behaves as if the original code had been executed. As long as a standard conforming program cannot detect the difference.  In your example, the caller can be compiled as y = x = my_function(). I can say that because I understand the code; a compiler may find it difficult to know that the change is valid.

Comment: @MartinMaat you seem be suggesting that optimising compilers can only do very little. Good ones are a lot more powerful than when I joined the industry. They can, and will, cache constant expressions if they can see that it will result in more efficient code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if the object no longer exists within the rules of the language, can it still be retained by the the compiler

Can it? Yes, so long as the language model doesn't forbid it. Does it? Check and see. You can say it should be optimized but I can call it a security risk. But we don't matter. What matters is what the model promised you, or didn't. If it didn't it's just an implementation detail of the compiler. It does whatever the implementer decides. The standards don't decide everything.

> Can I effectively treat a function call like a variable in a situation like this, without it being called each time, or should I assign an evaluation or function call to a named variable, if I want to use that value more than once?

This is a different question. To cache or not to cache is one of the hardest questions in computer science. Knowing if the compiler does it for you already would be nice to know but understand, just because your particular compiler behaves one way doesn't mean some poor unsuspecting fool wont come along later and notice that they can compile your code on something else. Something else that behaves differently.

So if you’re going to bake in assumptions about how your compiler is going to behave that are outside what the language standard guarantees I beg you to document them where such fools can easily find them. Because I've been such a fool. I was not amused.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My question is specifically, are compilers generally known to do this, particularly GCC. Or if this is something that is impossible or impractical to implement, and no compiler does this. I understand that a a feature can not be guaranteed if they are not specified by the standard, but I wondered if the is still something that I could generally expect from most compilers.